# RGBDSLAM error: Trust certificate g2o problem

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, g2o

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and ros fuerte. I am trying to run rgbdslam.

I followed the instructions given in this post [link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/50585/rgbdslam-error-in-fuerte-and-electric/): and I got the following error:

svn --non-interactive --config-dir /home/samme/trunk/g2o/svnconf co https://svn.openslam.org/data/svn/g2o/trunk build/g2o svn: OPTIONS of 'https://svn.openslam.org/data/svn/g2o/trunk': Server certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted (https://svn.openslam.org)

Note: I had previously downloaded g2o from the svn: https://openslam.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/data/svn/g2o/trunk/. I then moved the file trunk to the rubbish bin and downloaded g2o again from the svn : https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vslam/trunk/

I have been told to add the line: SVN_CMDLINE = svn--trust-server-cert--non-interactive --config-dir $(TOP_DIR)/svnconf to the makefile in the g2o folder.

However I am now getting this error:

svn--trust-server-cert--non-interactive --config-dir /home/samme/trunk/g2o/svnconf co  https://svn.openslam.org/data/svn/g2o/trunk build/g2o
make: svn--trust-server-cert--non-interactive: Command not found

Am I doing the command correctly? I really appreciate your help.

Regards,

Khalid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50745/rgbdslam-error:-trust-certificate-g2o-problem/) by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2012-12-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2012-12-18**:
I resolved this issue (the answer below), I have another problem, I will post it on a new thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution to this problem is adding this line: SVN_CMDLINE = svn --no-auth-cache --trust-server-cert --non-interactive instead of the one I mentioned earlier.

Regards,

Khalid

---

Originally posted by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) with karma: 735 on 2012-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2012-12-18**:
The author commented the wrong one I think. We encountered the same prob yesterday.

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2014-01-12**:
This does not work for me. The line is already in the Makefile.